# Setting volume does not work on one of my computers

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using this code to set the volume of my Flash video.

```
public function setVolume(loudness:Number):void
{
    // soundControl is a SoundTransform object
    this.soundControl.volume = loudness;

    // vidStream is a NetStream object
    this.vidStream.soundTransform = this.soundControl;

    trace("loudness = " + loudness);
}
```

I've tested this code on various operating systems. It works in all but one of my Windows 7 32-bit machines. On that machine, the volume is traced out correctly, but I don't hear any change. It will remain at full volume. How do I correct my code to work on all systems? Is my current way not standards compliant?

Comment: Flash Player is browser independent and as such it sould not be a change to your code. I would examine your embed code and start from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the newest Flash player and the problem is solved.